# Django admin - how can I use save_related() to parse data from inline forms?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I need to intercept when the user saves related (inline) data in django admin to call an external API.
I have the following models:

```
class Hostel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    descr = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ....

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    nick = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)

class HostelGuest(models.Model):
    hostel = models.ForeignKey(Hostel)
    guest = models.ForeignKey(User)
    entry_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)

class HostelEntryPoint(models.Model):
    hostel = models.ForeignKey(Hostel)  
    getting_here = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False)
    distance = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank = True)
```

In admin.py I have in the same page Hostel as parent and HostelGuest and EntryPoint as children. Whenever some data in HostelGuest changes, I need to find out if it's add/delete/update and call an external API. I thought of using save_related() but I'm unable to parse the data received and figure out the action taken. This is as far as I got, any help will be much appreciated!

```
class HostelEntryPointInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = HostelEntryPoint
    extra = 3

class HostelGuestInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model=HostelGuest
    extra=4

class HostelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [HostelGuestInline, HostelEntryPointInline]

    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        super(HostelAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        obj = form.instance
        obj.save()
        for formset in formsets:
            for f in formset:
                logger.error('form name:' + f.__class__.__name__)
                logger.error('form:' + f.cleaned_data['guest'])

admin.site.register(Hostel,HostelAdmin)
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone coming here looking for ways to hook into Django's M2M inline form changes (like I was) here's what I found simple and worked:

```py
class HostelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [HostelGuestInline, HostelEntryPointInline]

    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        for formset in formsets:
            # Found this simple way to check dynamic class instance.
            if formset.model == HostelGuest:
                instances = formset.save(commit=False)

                hostel = form.instance

                for added_hostel_guest in formset.new_objects:
                    # Do something with new objects added (not tested this, though)

                for deleted_hostel_guest in formset.deleted_objects:
                    do_something_with_deleted_guest_and_parent_instance(
                        deleted_hostel_guest.pk,
                        hostel.pk
                    )

        super(HostelAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Form` in your `admin.TabularInline`.

this is example.

```
class HostelGuestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # set your code.

class HostelGuestInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model=HostelGuest
    form = HostelGuestForm
    extra=4
```

if you want call external API, this is one of solutions.
you should type on your `class HostelAdmin`

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    if formset == formset_factory(HostelGuestForm):
        # this `if` is check for formset is for HostelGuest
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        # it returns your added, changed, deleted instance
        # if you don't have to check that instance is added or changed or deleted, below code is not required.
        for instance in instances:
            if instance.pk == None:
                # this is added
            elif:
                # check `change` for is changed or deleted
        formset.save_m2m()
    else:
        pass
```

the `def save_formset()` is called by `save_related()`, and the reason about **not change save_related, change save_formset** is for other `inline form`. because inline formset can possible for be added not only `HostelGuest`.

Comment: how can I tell which values were added/updated/deleted in HostelGuest?

Comment: @LeandroG you don't have to tell which values have changed. In admin, if you save your Hostel object, obj.save_related() will be call to save HostelGuest.

Comment: so, you can update or add or delete your HostelGuest just make HostelGuestForm. see this [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) and this [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_related)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm new to Django so sorry if my question doesn't make sense. What I need to do is "intercept" the action of add/update/delete in HostelGuest to call an external API. How can I do that in my HostelGuestForm

Comment: @LeandroG oh i reailize what really you want i will change my answer.

Comment: thanks for getting me on the right direction. I got compilation error @ "if formset == formset_factory(HostelGuestForm):" and in addition formset.save(commit=False) returned empty. What I ended up doing is "for f in formset" then inside the loop   f.cleaned_data['guest'] returned a HostelGuest object with the values entered in the form.